# Was Toad's slime attack meant to do more than kill Jean Grey in X1?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, toads-spit

During the short sequence between Jean Grey and Toad. Seeing Toad spit his slimy substance on Jean's face, was it strictly supposed to suffocate Jean Grey or was it also meant to carry an odor to make Jean suffocate quicker? I heard it was written in the script that it was supposed to knock her out. Was it intentionally to gross Jean out with the ick factor?

Comment: Worse than killed? You mean, like, [getting expelled?](http://cdn.quotesgram.com/img/84/19/566779167-hermione-harry-potter-expelled-quote-gif.gif) ;)

Answer (score 9):

The [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/X-Men.html) definitely does not say that:

> Suddenly, Toad lands in front of Jean, grabs her head and before
> she can react, his tongue launches at her face.
>
> **His tongue covers her face with an ADHESIVE SLIME.**  Jean
> falls to the ground.  Toad looks back at the main entrance, sees
> Cyclops emerging and LEAPS up, out of frame.
>
> ***ANGLE ON:***
>
> Cyclops stumbles out of the smoke filled building.  Seeing Jean
> lying on the ground, he runs to her.
>
> Cyclops turns Jean on her back, ready to perform CPR.  He is
> shocked, **the slime has now hardened to Jean's face.  She is
> suffocating.**  He desperately tries to pry it off.

So, it was merely meant to immobilize and suffocate her. No smell or ick attack.

Answer (score 1):

No, no smell or ick effect, the circumstances in the script are simply different than the film in some areas. The Statue of Liberty sequence is one of those areas. Here's how: Original Script-Cyclops, Storm, Jean Grey, and Rogue go to Liberty Island to save Wolverine, whose Adamtium skeleton is the catalyst for Magneto's machine.

Cyclops then splits the team into two groups, Storm and Rogue and himself and Jean. Cyclops and Jean are soon ambushed by Pyro in the torch room and Storm tells Rogue to run after sensing Toad nearby.

Jean finally manages to defeat Pyro by using her powers to slingshot two fire extinguishers in front of his flames, covering the now-dead mutant in foam and filling the torch room with a choking smoke, prompting Cyclops to make Jean run outside, where she is ambused by Toad, who uses his tongue to cover her face with an adhesive slime, blocking her air (this next part is very important).

Due to the fact that she was already struggling to catch her breath after escaping the smoke-filled torch room, having her face covered by  Toad's slime causes her to black out.

Toad then leaps out of frame as he sees Cyclops exit the building. Cyclops runs to Jean, and turns her on her back, ready to perform CPR, thinking she had inhaled too much smoke, only to discover Toad's slime.

Jean, now concsious, begins to panic as he tries to remove it. Storm and Toad then fight, which ends the same in both the script and movie. Jean becomes increasingly panicked as Cyclops struggles to remove the slime, her chest now hitching involuntarily for air.

Cyclops pins Jean down, forcing her to calm down, before using his optic blast to split the slime in half and pull the halves off. The script also included Beast and Blob, but due to budget issues, they were both reserved for later films and Pyro was reduced to a cameo as a student at the School for Gifted Youngsters.

Due to no longer having to fight both Pyro and Toad, when Jean is slimed by Toad, she is breathing normally, which makes the scene seem more different than it actually is.

Comment: Paragraph breaks = life

Answer (score -2):

While it isn’t directly stated anywhere in the script, in early versions of the movie the slime was alluded to being intentionally gross on a few occasions, and in some comics it is acidic. More than likely, the slime was just meant to suffocate Jean, but it was used as a sort of gross out attack because it is gross and Toad was supposed to be a gross character.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If you have any evidence that this was intended to be the case in the movie you should [edit] your answer to add it.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this bold statement?